Is there a carousel that works in react-remix?
I've been struggling trying to find a carousel that works with react-remix. I've tried embla, swiper, React Slick, React Alice Carousel, etc.
Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but I either can't figure out how to integrate my already written react index function text onto the slides (since multiple headers and other lines would go on each slide) or I get an error not recognizing the object from the library that I imported (like <Slider> from react-slick). If you don't know any carousels that work with remmix, how would I code my own slider?

I suggest you to use shadcn which is a ui component library build top for radix ui, and It has a customizable carousel https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/carousel
